# How can I multiply every element in one list by every element in another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Take the lists:

```
["nae", "red"]
[5, 2, 3]
```

Print out the following using a for loop:

```
"nnnnnaaaaaeeeee"
"nnaaee"
"nnnaaaeee"
"rrrrreeeeeddddd"
"rreedd"
"rrreeeddd"
```

---

Here's what I have so far:

```py
list1 = ["nae", "red"]
list2 = [5, 2, 3]

z = 0

for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        print(list1[z]*list2[z])
        z = z + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues with your solution is that you're not iterating over the characters of each string. Here's one solution:

```py
strings = ["nae", "red"]
mults = [5, 2, 3]

for string in strings:
    for mult in mults:
        s = ""
        for char in string:
            s += char * mult
        print(s)
```

Output:

```
nnnnnaaaaaeeeee
nnaaee
nnnaaaeee
rrrrreeeeeddddd
rreedd
rrreeeddd
```

Comment: Thanks -- this was really helpful. I now see how my iteration wasn't set up correctly.

Comment: @Sean if you're satisfied with mine or anybody else's answer, go ahead and mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the pairs, then [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to construct the final strings.

```
from itertools import product

words = ["nae", "red"]
numbers = [5, 2, 3]

for w, n in product(words, numbers):
    print(''.join(letter * n for letter in w))
```

Outputs

```
nnnnnaaaaaeeeee
nnaaee
nnnaaaeee
rrrrreeeeeddddd
rreedd
rrreeeddd
```

Comment: I tend to disagree with showing more "advanced" techniques to people that are clearly new to the language/programming.

Comment: @blorgon Python is a batteries-included language, the sooner a new programmer realizes it, the more time they have to focus on solving actual problems than re-implementing the wheel

Comment: Not understanding basic logic will hurt new programmers in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ["nae", "red"]
list2 = [5, 2, 3]
r = [''.join(k*a for k in b) for a in list2 for b in list1]
```

Output:

```
['nnnnnaaaaaeeeee', 'rrrrreeeeeddddd', 'nnaaee', 'rreedd', 'nnnaaaeee', 'rrreeeddd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

- Iterate over each word.
- Iterate over each required appearance.
- mult the required appearance with each char in the word.

  words_ls = ["nae", "red"]

  appearances = [5, 2, 3]

  def dup_ch(words_ls, appearances):
  for item in words_ls:
  new_word = ''
  for ap in appearances:
  for c in item:
  new_word+=c*ap
  print(new_word)

Comment: Please explain your solution a bit more, so that the OP can understand it.